# Preferred way build an instance of AmazonS3Client with AWSCredentials

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

[AmazonS3Client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#AmazonS3Client--) has been deprecated in favor of [AmazonS3ClientBuilder](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3ClientBuilder.html). AmazonS3Client constructor accepted instance of AWSCredentials through which client can pass on AWS Access and Secret Key.

```
AWSCredentials credentialsProvider = ... ;
AmazonS3Client amazonS3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentialsProvider.getCredentials());
```

When using AmazonS3ClientBuilder what is the preferred way to instantiate an AmazonS3 client with the necessary AWS credentials?

Comment: According to the docs, this seems to be the preferred approach: `AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(new EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider()).build();`. You can adjust the `AWSCredentialsProvider` with your own implementation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html), you can use the `AmazonS3ClientBuilder` as follows:

```
AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                   .withCredentials(new EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider())
                   .build();
```

The EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider used here,

> provides credentials by looking at the: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (or AWS_ACCESS_KEY) and AWS_SECRET_KEY (or AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY) environment variables.

Source: [AWS Documentation EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/amazonaws/auth/EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider.html)

Alternatively you can adjust the [AWSCredentialsProvider](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/amazonaws/auth/AWSCredentialsProvider.html) with your own implementation.

> You can use this technique to supply credential providers or provider chains that you create by using your own credential provider that implements the AWSCredentialsProvider interface

Or you can use an implementation provided by Amazon, e.g. the [BasicAWSCredentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/BasicAWSCredentials.html) class provided:

```
BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("access_key_id", "secret_key_id");
AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
    .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
    .withRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2)
    .build();
```

More official classes that implement the interface are:

- [AnonymousAWSCredentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/AnonymousAWSCredentials.html): implementation that allows anonymous credentials
- [BasicSessionCredentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/BasicSessionCredentials.html): Session credentials with keys and session token.
- [PropertiesCredentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/PropertiesCredentials.html): reads AWS access keys from a properties file. The AWS access key is expected to be in the "accessKey" property and the AWS secret key id is expected to be in the "secretKey" property.
- [STSSessionCredentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/STSSessionCredentials.html): Session credentials periodically refreshed by AWS SecurityTokenServic

Comment: but how do I get `AmazonS3Client` by `AmazonS3`

Comment: Hi @袁文涛: 
I'm not sure I understand the question. `AmazonS3` is an interface, meaning you have to use an implementing class. This could be either `AmazonS3Client` or any other class that implements said interface, e.g.  `AmazonS3EncryptionClient`, `AmazonS3EncryptionClientV2`, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html

To use any of the aforementioned classes, use the AWS SDK for Java: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html